# How can I make file validation if field does not exist on DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4.0

I have item model.
Item new form has image field that does not exist on DB.
Because I want to save files on directory.

But how can I make validation for file field?

Comment: You add a field for it in the model and database.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an `attr_accessor` to your model.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :file

  validates_presence_of :file
end
```

Then in the form

```
<%= f.file_field :file %>
```

That is one option but I would recommend looking into using [Carrier Wave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for file uploads. The files are still saved on the file system and are only referenced in the database by their file names.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work
Despite I attached file, file field says can't be blank.
I think it is because file field does not exist on DB...

Comment: I tried this for text field, then it worked.
Does file field has special validation or something?

Comment: Finally it worked!! Thanks!!
What important was this
    params.require(:item).permit(:title, :comment, :file)

Thanks so much